# IID_PPV_ARGS is not declared when compiling with wineg++

Tags: c++, com, directx-11, wine, imgui

****SHORT VERSION:****

> `IID_PPV_ARGS()` is not declared with wineg++. Is there a replacement?

****LONG VERSION:****

> I'm trying to make a DX11 GUI with imgui. However, I'm on Linux and I don't have enough RAM to have a reliable virtual machine running Windows so I'm using wineg++ to compile the code on my system.
>
> imgui provides some examples for different frameworks to create GUIs, which includes DX11 with either [SDL2](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/tree/master/examples/example_sdl2_directx11) or [WIN32](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_win32_directx11/main.cpp). I tried compiling the SDL2 example but it's very windows specific with a missing <process.h> header for threading which apparently doesn't have a fix for POSIX systems, so that was a dead end. That leaves me with the WIN32 example.
>
> When compiling with `wineg++ -Iimgui/ -Iimgui/backends/ dx11.cpp -o main`, I keep getting this error:
>
> ```
> error: ‘IID_PPV_ARGS’ was not declared in this scope
> ```
>
> I then included the <combaseapi.h> header according to the [MSVC docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) for the macro, but the problem still persists. Is there a way to replace this macro?

Answer (score 0):

solved, I changed this:

```cpp
g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBackBuffer));
```

to this:

```cpp
g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pBackBuffer));
```

Comment: Does the compiler support `__declspec(uuid)` and `__uuidof()`, or equivalent? If so, then declare the macro manually in your code: `#define IID_PPV_ARGS(ppType) __uuidof(*ppType), reinterpret_cast<void**>(ppType)`